# Twitter OAuth 1.0 to access user email address

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

From my readings, it seems like Twitter's OAuth V2 is not giving the email of the user when you authorize an app, which is clearly hard then to know which user is linked to who.

Then I've seen that the Oauth V1 might help to have back the email of the user, but in order to have something working, you need to make 3 requests.

So maybe someone can help me here and let me know how can I let a user authorize my app like with oAuth V2?

```
// route.js
import axios from 'axios';
import {v1 as uuidv1} from 'uuid';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import qs from 'qs';
import oauthSignature from 'oauth-signature';

// routes.js - /auth/twitter
// this should return a oauth_token / oauth_token_secret / oauth_callback_confirmed
// https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens


    const oauth_nonce = uuidv1();
    const oauth_timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);


    const oauth_signature_rfc_b64 = oauthSignature.generate('POST', process.env.TWITTER_AUTH_TOKEN_URL, {
      include_entities: true,
      oauth_consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY,
      oauth_nonce,
      oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',      
      oauth_timestamp,
      oauth_token: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      oauth_version: "1.0",
    }, process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY_SECRET, process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    
    const response = await axios.post(
      process.env.TWITTER_AUTH_TOKEN_URL, '',
      {headers: {
        oauth_consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY,
        oauth_token: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
        oauth_version: "1.0",
        oauth_callback: process.env.TWITTER_REDIRECT_URL,
        oauth_nonce,
        oauth_timestamp,
        oauth_signature: oauth_signature_rfc_b64
      }},
    );
```

I've switched almost every parameters, API_KEY, SECRET, headers, params etc etc but nothing is working and I get an error code 32 from the Twitter response, but nothing else.

If someone has already used node and Axios to craft this kind of request or know how to use OAuth 1.0 to do the same as OAuth 2.0 could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the v2 API does not provide access to a user's email address (although this is a known request, and may be added in the future). Since you are using JavaScript, you can use any of the [existing JavaScript client libraries for the API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries/v1) that will wrap up the OAuth process for you.